# How can I tell what subclass was saved?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a model with 2 subclasses:

```
public class User
{
    public string eRaiderUsername { get; set; }
    public int AllowedSpaces { get; set; }
    public ContactInformation ContactInformation { get; set; }
    public Ethnicity Ethnicity { get; set; }
    public Classification Classification { get; set; }
    public Living Living { get; set; }
}

public class Student : User
{
    public Student()
    {
        AllowedSpaces = AppSettings.AllowedStudentSpaces;
    }
}

public class OrganizationRepresentative : User
{
    public Organization Organization { get; set; }

    public OrganizationRepresentative()
    {
        AllowedSpaces = AppSettings.AllowedOrganizationSpaces;
    }
}

public class ContactInformation
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string CellPhoneNumber { get; set; }
}

public enum Ethnicity
{
    AfricanAmerican,
    AmericanIndian,
    Asian,
    Black,
    Hispanic,
    NativeHawaiian,
    NonResidentAlien,
    White
}

public enum Classification
{
    Freshman,
    Sophomore,
    Junior,
    Senior,
    GraduateStudent
}

public enum Living
{
    OnCompus,
    OffCampus
}
```

This is (mostly) saving fine using these initializers:

```
 var students = new List<Student>
 {
     new Student{ eRaiderUsername="somestudent", ContactInformation=new ContactInformation{FirstName="Some", LastName="Student", EmailAddress="student@example.com", CellPhoneNumber="1234567890"}, Classification=Classification.Junior, Ethnicity=Ethnicity.Hispanic, Living=Living.OffCampus }
 };
 students.ForEach(s => context.Users.Add(s));
 context.SaveChanges();

 var orgReps = new List<OrganizationRepresentative>
 {
     new OrganizationRepresentative{ eRaiderUsername="somerep", ContactInformation=new ContactInformation{FirstName="Some", LastName="Representative", EmailAddress="orgrep@example.com", CellPhoneNumber="0987654321"}, Classification=Classification.Freshman, Ethnicity=Ethnicity.White, Living=Living.OnCompus, Organization=context.Organizations.Find(1) }
 };
 orgReps.ForEach(o => context.Users.Add(o));
 context.SaveChanges();
```

None of the enums are saving (advice on this would be awesome too). But everything else is saving fine.

**I have noticed Entity has added a Discriminator column with the subclass names. How do I use this to query only students, only organization reps, or just tell if the current object is a student or organization rep in a controller or view?**

Comment: Advice on enum: Are you targeting .NET Framework 4 or 4.5? Also, what version of EF are you using? EF4 will not save enums with .NET Framework 4. Can you check updating your records with .NET 4.5 and Entity Framework 5 and above? More on this on msdn: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh859576.aspx

Comment: @ACS ah - you nailed it. Deployment environment is .Net 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The discriminator column is used internally by EF to determine the type of object to instantiate.

For example you could query for a student directly. `context.Set<Student>.Find(id)`. The same is true for an org rep. Or you could query for any user `context.Set<User>.Find(id)`.

If you query for a student, but pass an org rep's ID, then EF will return null, because the ID doesn't belong to a student.